# Android 2D Game Development: How to handle the background/rendering in general?

Tags: android, 2d

I'm currently trying to create a 2D Android based game for my Android App Dev. class, and after making the layouts and finishing up everything else, I realized that I don't have a clue as to how to render the images and how to have a scrolling background for my game.

The Idea:

- It will be a very simple 2D game

  - kirby will be the main character (kinda already understand how to animate images)
  - 2 enemies (wanted them to walk. but since project is due in 4 days, they can stand)
  - kirby can only move left/right and jump (which i will figure out later haha)
    -

The Research
    -

- I have looked for around 5~6hrs for the last couple of days and cant figure it out

  - The main problem I am having is that I understand that Canvas/OpenGL is used to make the background and render Images but I cant find any videos or easier tutorials on making the level scroll as I want it too or the code.(if you dont know what kirby is, the level scrolls similar to mario style, kirby xpos +  = level xpos + is what I think the code would be like...)

Yes I know that this is sort of waiting to the last minute, but any help would be much appreciated !

Thanks Again,
Gabe

Comment: You will have to have a thread-engine responsible for updating the state of all objects in your game world and rendering all the UI based on the current state. Also, google for a thing called Camera. This idea is employed when the world is scrolled around the main character. Here is a good tutorial about platform games like yours: 
http://www.wildbunny.co.uk/blog/2011/12/11/how-to-make-a-2d-platform-game-part-1/
P.S. here is the youtube link on the howto explaining a basic game engine in java (can be easily re-applied to android)
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IyVYDYB3sv0

Comment: Thanks alex.veprik, Wow you found some material in like 10 minutes haha, I will read/watch this stuff for a bit and hopefully be able to finish this game by Tuesday. Thanks again for your help!